# Utilizing InStr to compare two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I've spent hours trying to figure out the best way to solve this problem and I have no solution. I've tried loops, using InStr, conditional formatting w/ wildcards, but the results are never what I want.

I've got two columns of values, one with the values I want to search for and the other with a long string that my value could be sitting in anywhere, hence my need for wildcards. What I want to do is take the first row of the long string column and compare it to every value in the column with the shorter values. If none of the shorter values are found in the long string, delete the row with the long string and move to the next one...

I'm thinking I have to set it up something like this:

```
For i = 1 to lastrow,
    If InStr(longvalue, shortvalue) Then
    ' Break loop to next i?
    Else
        If i = lastrow
             longvalue.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Any help would be appreciated... been pulling my hair out over this one.

Taking another look, I think I would need 2 loops, the first one to cycle through all the short values with the single longer value, then after they've all been cycled through, go to the next longer value.

EDIT: Ended with this:

```
i = 6
j = 2
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SM Summaries")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
reallastrow = lastrow + 1
For i = 6 To reallastrow
    For j = 2 To 82
        If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C" & i).Value, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Reference Sheet").Range("H" & j).Value) Then
            Exit For
        Else
            If j = 82 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("C" & i).EntireRow.ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deleting rows in a  loop, you need to loop backwards so the loop can keep track of the correct row. So,

```
For i=lastrow to 1 step -1
    If InStr(longvalue, shortvalue) Then
        GoTo Nexti
    end if
    if i=1 then
        longvalue.entirerow.delete 'this assumes longvalue is a cell reference
    end if
Nexti:
Next i
```

But I think I would use [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("b1:b500") 
for i=lastrow to 1 step -1
    Set c = .Find(cells(i,1), lookin:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)  'xlPart returns true if just part of the string matches
    If c Is Nothing Then 'didn't find your string
        cells(i,2).entirerow.delete
    end if
next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! I just figured it out. Pretty much the same answer as your first bit of code. I was stepping forward through my loop and using clearcontents instead of deleterow, because at the end of my code I delete all blanks and duplicates anyways and it all is shifted up. Whatever works!

Comment: OK. Good. Also maybe experiment with `Find` as the code is more succinct. Congrats on figuring it out, though.

Comment: So does `Find` automatically utilize wildcards, so even if my value was a substring in a bigger string, that would pass?

Comment: Yes, by including the argument, `lookat:=xlPart`, as in my alternative solution. I find this function extremely valuable.